# AD nested group membership powershell reporting

Tags: powershell, active-directory, reporting, powershell-3.0

We have following naming convention for shared resources:

```
sg_ShareName1_RO
sg_ShareName1_RW
sg_ShareName2_RO
sg_ShareName2_RW
```

I would like to get report in following format in Excel/csv:

```
         ShareName1    ShareName2 ...
User1    RW            NA
User2    NA            RO
```

I'm fighting how to output Shared names to row in csv file instead of column.
Here is come code I've already done:

```
 $users = GetADUser - filter {name like '*'} | sort name | select name
 $sharegroups = Get-AdGroup -filter {name like 'sg_*'} | sort name
 $shares = Get-AdGroup -filter {name like 'sg_*'} | sort name | foreach {$_} | select @{N='Share Name'; E={$_.Name.Replace('sg_', '').Replace('_', '').Replace('RO','').Replace('RW','')}} -Unique
```

Tnen to avoid trips to AD each time to check group membership first i would like to store members of each group in array

```
$sharegroupmembers = @{}
foreach ($group in $sharegroups)
{
   $sharegroupmembers[$group.name] = Get-ADGroupMember $group.name -Recursive | select name
}
```

After that I'm stuck on howe to make correct projection of shares to columns, users to rows and RW/RO/NA to values based on group membership

Answer (score 0):

Your number of columns is going to be the maximum number of group memeberships any user has.  Those are in the values of $sharegroupmembers, so:

```
$shargroupmembers.values | 
sort count |
select -last 1
```

That's how many rows you'll have, and how many share membership properties you'll need to create on your objects you're going to export.